# What Achievements, Titles, Items, Mounts and Pets, (etc.) Are being removed in Patch 5.0/Mists of Pandaria?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

WoW has a long history of removing content with the release of new expansions. While the most obvious case of this was the removal of, for example, Zul Gurub, and with it, the old Tiger and Raptor mounts with the release of Cataclysm, there have been several other examples of now classic titles or items that are no longer obtainable because the quests required to reach them, or the dungeons in which they dropped, or whatever, have since been removed from the game.

And just as the removal of content is something of an age old tradition, so is using the lull before a new expansion to farm up those last few achievements, to waste time grinding that one rep that's about to be removed, or farming a dungeon to get that one last piece of that old tier .5 gear that you won't be able to get anymore to complete your set.

But so far, as the release date for Mists rapidly approaches, I'm yet to see a list of exactly what's going away, which is of course, an important tool before engaging in such an exercise.

So, what's being removed? I'm especially interested in titles, achievements, mounts and pets, but any notable reputations, set items or cosmetic items, are of course worth mentioning as well.

Comment: Can't cite sources but it will be likely that 'I can't hear you over the sound of how awesome I am' is removed (I have heard rumours that this will be a FoS), and the drop chance of Pureblood Firehawk/Lifebinders' Handmaiden nerfed to a similar level as Invincible was at the start of Cataclysm. There were no 'immortal' style titles in Cataclysm so I do not think any of the titles will be removed.

Comment: ZG was removed yes but they did put it back in the current 5 man heroic version, that statement could confuse future visitors/readers without clarification imo.

Comment: I've made a [guide](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1050/thats-so-last-expansion-worthwhile-stuff-removed-changed-in-mop) on potential things that might be changed.  Note that it's just that they _may_ be changed.  When they redid Deadmines and Shadowfang keep, some of the items (Defias Leather, etc) didn't make it into the overhaul, which is why I listed the items.

Comment: Head enchants are getting removed - [source](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5149537803#9)

Comment: @Blem as a non-cosmetic item of purely mechanical value, which will cease to function in 5.0, those are not particularly interesting.

Answer (score 4):

One thing that has been **confirmed** by Blizzard as changing is [the drop rate of some raid mounts will decrease](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5071488033?page=5#95) [on release of Mists of Pandaria](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/5071488033?page=8#158), specifically [Smoldering Egg of Millagazor](http://mop.wowhead.com/item=69224) and [Life-Binder's Handmaiden](http://mop.wowhead.com/item=77069), both currently 100% drops on heroic raid encounters.

As far as we know at this point there are no dungeons being removed, no old questlines being removed and no old reputations being removed.  Almost all new content, with the exception of Pet Battles, the Fall of Theramore and Heroic SM and Scholomance, is Pandaria-based.  As far as we know, achievements, titles, mounts, etc, will remain achieveable with the usual exception of the rotating PvP mounts.

Doing a comparison of data-mined Feats of Strength backs this up, with only new Realm Firsts, new expansion Feats and the PvP stuff the difference between the [current list of Feats](http://www.wowhead.com/achievements=1.81) and the [list for Mists](http://mop.wowhead.com/achievements=1.81).

Comment: Theramore's Fall? other wise a good answer

Comment: Good catch, but I'm not sure how much that actually affects Theramore - will it remove all the levelling quests?  Plus there aren't really any titles, achievements, mounts or pets that come out of there, which is what he's asking about.

Comment: We now know more about Theramore.  Right now, there is only "pre-fall" Theramore.  1 week before MoP release, the scenario will open.  Characters that complete the scenario will see "post-fall" Theramore, while characters that don't will see "pre-fall".  This state of affairs will remain for some months after MoP launch until a switch is thrown and everyone will see "post-fall" Theramore - even characters that have not done the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to post this as an answer, since it technically is.

While there aren't any absolutes on what will be changed or removed, we do know what will be getting makeovers, and we know how things worked in previous expansions.  Although that still doesn't help much with solid answers, a list of worthwhile things that may be changed or removed can be generated to help prepare yourself just in case.

I've made such a list, and it's hosted at [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1050/thats-so-last-expansion-worthwhile-stuff-removed-changed-in-mop).  Remember, this is just what *may* be changed.  It is not complete and it is not final; it's just a tentative resource.